# chrono_literals is not a namespace-name

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-chrono

I am trying to build a program called darkstar a private FFXI server. I am trying to build this on FreeBSD 10.2 stable. I am using GCC 5.3 from ports to try to build this.

Using this  make CC=gcc5 CXX=g++5 CPP="gcc5 -E" to call the correct version of GCC/G++.

This is the error code I get kicked out.

```
src/common/../common/../common/cbasetypes.h:336:22: error: 'chrono_literals'         is not a namespace-name
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                  ^
src/common/../common/../common/cbasetypes.h:336:37: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

I have checked to make sure that chrono is actually in the correct spot which it is it is at /usr/include/c++/v1/chrono.

Where the error is getting thrown this is the code that is from the line 336 in cbasetypes.h and the few lines after.

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using server_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using time_point = server_clock::time_point;
using duration = server_clock::duration;
```

Not sure what to do to work around this error though I figured this community would be a good place to start.

Comment: Could be on crack here so this isn't an answer, but try `std::literals::chrono_literals`.

Comment: Thank you, but no sadly this does not work.

Comment: Another question are you compiling with the dialect set to c++11 or 14? chrono_literals is new to 14. I believe the switch is `-std=c++1y`

Comment: CXX = g++ -std=c++1y and CFLAGS_ALL+= -std=c++11 both are in my Makefile.am

Comment: You access the namespace with `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals`. C++14, so remove the c++11 flag from your makefile.

Comment: Captain Giraffe thank you :D  I changed that in coding and changed makefile to call c++14 only. Got it to build a great deal farther. Any idea how to fix 'to string' is not a member of std? Guessing that this error is along the same lines as this.

Comment: @user6031824 it is `-std=c++14`.

Comment: I run into this problem when I added the namespace to the newer version of the same file.  I forgot the delete the old version in a different location.  The compiler found the old version first.  Do a find /some/include/dir -name your_header.h

Answer (score 21):

You misspelt `std::literals::chrono_literals`.

Remember to ensure that you're compiling the source according to C++14 (the chrono literals are not provided in C++11).

Comment: I got past that thank you using,                            std::literals::chrono_literals                                                                          g++ -std=c++14                                                                                                 and then flags -std=gnu++14, -std=c++14.

Comment: For the record, you should be able to just use `std::chrono_literals` as long as you're compiling from C++14: "These operators are declared in the namespace `std::literals::chrono_literals`, where both `literals` and `chrono_literals` are inline namespaces. **Access to these operators can be gained with** `using namespace std::literals`, **`using namespace std::chrono_literals`**, and `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals`." (emphasis mine) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h

Comment: No offense, but this question/answer is receiving _a lot_ of reputation for simply [a missing compiler option](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7gsa5)... adding `-std=c++14` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
```

And add this in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <chrono>
 
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

will do, but you will need at least the C++14 compilation flag.